# Control xaxis tick mark size on all subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the below code, which works to a point. However, it only changes the size of the xticks for one of the subplots. How can I change it to change the size for all of them?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

input_file = 'CSP.csv'
output_file = 'sub_plots.png'
df = pd.read_csv(input_file, header = 0)
classes = ['SD','SC','FIR','MD','UA','LB']

f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 3)
f.tight_layout()

i=0
for r in range(2):
    for c in range(3):
        axarr[r][c].hist(df.CSP_change[(df.Class==classes[i])].values,10,rwidth=1, alpha=0.3)
        axarr[r][c].set_title(classes[i])
        axarr[r][c].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
        axarr[r][c].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        axarr[r][c].spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)
        axarr[r][c].spines['left'].set_visible(True)
        axarr[r][c].get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
        axarr[r][c].get_yaxis().tick_left()
        plt.xticks(fontsize=6)
        i += 1

#save
plt.savefig(output_file)
```

[image: histogram]

I tried changing plt to axarr[r][c] but it gave me an error message about not having attribute xticks.

Comment: Did you try moving the `plt.xticks(fontsize=6)` line outside the loop?

Comment: @KunalVyas that will only change it for the last subplot created (as it does now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`plt.xticks` only acts on the final subplot axes created. You want to set it on all the subplots. You have two options:

1) You can set the tick label size for each axes using the [`tick_params`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) property of the axes. Use this line instead of the `plt.xticks` line you currently have:

```
axarr[r][c].tick_params(axis='x',labelsize=6)
```

2) You can set it globally for all subplots using [`rcParams`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) (as suggested by @DavidG). Put this line before you create the figure and axes:

```
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 6
```

Comment: I suppose it would be more 'pythonic' to use the first method to change the tick size of that individual figure rather than setting it globally? But both would get the same outcome I suppose.

Comment: Yes, both get the same outcome in this case. It depends on what you want to do - for example, you may have other subplots created in the same script for which you want a different size label, in which case you don't want to set them globally.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest solution is to do:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

# some code here

f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 3)
f.tight_layout()

label_size = 6
mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = label_size #add these lines in 

# the rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Accepted the other answer as it was a bit more flexible even though that wasn't in my question.

Comment: No problem, the other answer was more complete and gave another (probably better) way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach would let you set it on a per subplot basis:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

input_file = 'CSP.csv'
output_file = 'sub_plots.png'
df = pd.read_csv(input_file, header = 0)
classes = ['SD','SC','FIR','MD','UA','LB']

f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 3)
f.tight_layout()
i=0

plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=6)

for rows in axarr:
    for ax_c in rows:
        ax_c.hist(df.values, 10, rwidth=1, alpha=0.3)
        ax_c.set_title(classes[i])
        ax_c.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
        ax_c.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        ax_c.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)
        ax_c.spines['left'].set_visible(True)
        ax_c.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
        ax_c.get_yaxis().tick_left()
        ax_c.tick_params(labelsize=6)
        i += 1

#save
plt.savefig(output_file)
```

Comment: note this will change the `yticklabel` size as well